# SQLite throws error "Foreign key mismatch"

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

In my SQLite database I created three tables as below.

```
CREATE TABLE OBTTourHeader
(
TourHeaderCode INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
VehicleCode VARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
LastMilage DOUBLE,
TourReference VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
TourFromDate TEXT  NOT NULL,
TourToDate TEXT  NOT NULL,
TourAssignTo VARCHAR(30)  ,
DriverNmae VARCHAR(30)  ,
AssistantName VARCHAR(30)  ,
Porter1Name VARCHAR(30)  ,
Porter2Name VARCHAR(30)  ,
Porter3Name VARCHAR(30)  ,
RouteCode INT,
Active CHAR(1)  NOT NULL,
CreatedOn TEXT ,
CreatedBy CHAR(10),
UpdateOn TEXT,
Updateby CHAR(10)
);



CREATE TABLE OBTTourDetails
(
TourHeaderCode INT    NOT NULL,
TourdetailCode INT    NOT NULL,
VisitSequence INT NOT NULL,
LocationNmae VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
CityName VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
Type CHAR(1)   NOT NULL,
Status CHAR(1)   NOT NULL,
TypeColor CHAR(20)  ,
statusColor CHAR(20)  ,
Active CHAR(1)  NOT NULL,
CreatedOn TEXT ,
CreatedBy CHAR(10),
UpdateOn TEXT,
Updateby CHAR(10),
FOREIGN KEY (TourHeaderCode) REFERENCES OBTTourHeader(TourHeaderCode),
PRIMARY KEY (TourHeaderCode , TourdetailCode)

);


CREATE TABLE OBTTourDropPickItems
(
TourHeaderCode INT NOT NULL,
TourdetailCode INT NOT NULL,
DropPickupItemCode INT NOT NULL,
Status CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
CreatedOn TEXT ,
CreatedBy CHAR(10),
UpdateOn TEXT,
Updateby CHAR(10),
FOREIGN KEY (TourHeaderCode) REFERENCES OBTTourHeader(TourHeaderCode),
FOREIGN KEY (TourdetailCode) REFERENCES OBTTourDetails(TourdetailCode),
PRIMARY KEY (TourHeaderCode, TourdetailCode, DropPickupItemCode)


);
```

And I tried to enter a record using the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO OBTTourDropPickItems (TourHeaderCode, TourdetailCode, DropPickupItemCode, Status, CreatedOn, CreatedBy)
VALUES ('1','1','1','1','21/01/2013','samantha');
```

It gives me a error "foreign key mismatch":

[image]

I couldn't figure out the error. Both **OBTTourDetails** table and **OBTTourHeader** table contain records. What's going wrong here? To me it's seems like it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make Foreign key, a Primary key of the same table. You are doing this mistake in `OBTTourDropPickItems` table.

**Mistake:**

```
PRIMARY KEY (TourHeaderCode, TourdetailCode, DropPickupItemCode)
```

**Solution:**

```
TourHeaderCode INT NOT NULL REFERENCES OBTTourHeader,
TourdetailCode INT NOT NULL REFERENCES OBTTourDetails,
PRIMARY KEY (TourHeaderCode, TourdetailCode, DropPickupItemCode)
```

Comment: Can't I use primary key by combining these three (TourHeaderCode, TourdetailCode, DropPickupItemCode)

Comment: What you are looking for is composite primary key. And you are doing it the wrong way.

Comment: OK. But when I'm entering data into OBTTourDetails table, it gave no error. It also have a same kind of primary key.

Comment: I defined TourHeaderCode  and TourdetailCode  as not null.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) says:

> Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key of the parent table. If they are not the primary key, then the parent key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or have a UNIQUE index.

Your `OBTTourDetails(TourdetailCode)` column has no such index.

Comment: TourdetailCode is a part of composite primary key. Is it not valid in this case????

Comment: When a column is only *part of* a primary key, it is possible to insert non-unique values into this column (by having unique values in the other PK columns).